# Angular2 rc1: how to use nested ControlGroups?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-forms

Please, can someone help me to understand how control group works.
I’m trying to do something like this

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup } from "@angular/common";
import { NestedFieldset } from "./nested.fieldset.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [
    NestedFieldset
  ],
  template: `
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [ngFormModel]="form">
    <nested-fieldset ngControlGroup="abFields" [parentForm]="form"></nested-fieldset>

    <label>field c: </label>
    <input placeholder="fieldC" ngControl="fieldC"/> <br>

    <button (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">fancy submit</button>
  </form>
`})
export class AppComponent {
  form: ControlGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      abFields: NestedFieldset.getControlGroup(fb),
      fieldC: ['']
    });
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(" fancy was submitted")
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }
}
```

nested.fieldset.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { TranslatePipe } from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";
import { FormBuilder, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'nested-fieldset',
  directives: [
    FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
  <fieldset [ngFormModel]="parentForm">
    <label>field a: </label><input placeholder="fieldA"/> <br>
    <label>field b: </label><input placeholder="fieldB"/> <br>
  </fieldset>
  `
})
export class NestedFieldset {

  @Input()
  parentForm: ControlGroup;

  constructor() {}

  static getControlGroup(fb: FormBuilder) {
    return fb.group({
      fieldA: [''],
      fieldB: ['']
    });
  }
}
```

On submit `fieldC` is OK, but i cant access values from nested `fieldset` (`fieldA` and `fieldB`).

Whats wrong?

you can view live example on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EDqloxqd8xbByejEUZZx?p=preview

Comment: I'm very sorry, i forgot about ngControls -) . also, i use [ngFormModel]="parentForm.find('abFields')" in nested-fieldset

Answer (score 2):

There is the [updated and working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ScCbDmdGXgmguYkHc0Yk?p=preview)

I would define all the `form` stuff at one place (e.g. where form is now created), and pass to child just related group

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: ControlGroup;
  result: any;

  // create form at once      
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      //abFields: NestedFieldset.getControlGroup(fb),
      abFields: fb.group({
        fieldA: [''],
        fieldB: [''],
      }),
      fieldC: ['']
    });
  }
}
```

The template:

```
  // just the abFields group is passed
  template: `
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [ngFormModel]="form">
    <nested-fieldset [controlGroup]="form.find('abFields')" ></nested-fieldset>

    <label>field c: </label>
    <input placeholder="fieldC" ngControl="fieldC"/> <br>

    <button (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">fancy submit</button>
  </form>
  <pre>
  {{result | json}}
  </pre>
`})
```

And child would be like that:

```
// see the [ngFormControl]="controlGroup.find('..') in action
@Component({
  selector: 'nested-fieldset',
  directives: [
    FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
  <fieldset >
    <label>field a: </label>
       <input placeholder="fieldA" [ngFormControl]="controlGroup.find('fieldA')"/> <br>
    <label>field b: </label>
       <input placeholder="fieldB" [ngFormControl]="controlGroup.find('fieldB')"/> <br>
  </fieldset>
  `
})
export class NestedFieldset {

  @Input() 
  controlGroup: ControlGroup;

  constructor() {}

}
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ScCbDmdGXgmguYkHc0Yk?p=preview)

NOTE: I would start to observe the RC2 world

**https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub**

Answer (score 2):

Forgot about ngControls in 
nested.fieldset.component.ts:

```
 template: `
  <fieldset [ngFormModel]="parentForm">
    <label>field a: </label><input placeholder="fieldA" ngControl="fieldA"/> <br>
    <label>field b: </label><input placeholder="fieldB" ngControl="fieldB"/> <br>
  </fieldset>
```

and

app.component.ts should use:

```
[parentForm]="form.find('abFields')"
```

instead of:

```
[parentForm]="form"
```